# How to take average(mean) of timestamp('yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss') in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hql, hiveql

I have a logs table. look like this:-

```
  user_name               idle_hours            working_hours       start_time       stop_time
sahil24c@gmail.com     2019-10-24 05:05:00  2019-10-24 05:50:00  2019-10-24 08:30:02  2019-10-24 19:25:02
magadum@gmail.com      2019-10-24 02:15:00  2019-10-24 08:39:59  2019-10-24 08:30:02  2019-10-24 19:25:01
yathink3@gmail.com     2019-10-24 01:30:00  2019-10-24 09:24:59  2019-10-24 08:30:02  2019-10-24 19:25:01
shelkeva@gmail.com     2019-10-24 00:30:00  2019-10-24 09:10:01  2019-10-24 08:45:01  2019-10-24 18:25:02
puruissim@gmail.com    2019-10-24 03:15:00  2019-10-24 07:19:59  2019-10-24 08:50:02  2019-10-24 19:25:01
sangita.awa@gmail.com  2019-10-24 01:55:00  2019-10-24 08:40:00  2019-10-24 08:50:01  2019-10-24 19:25:01
vaishusawan@gmail.com  2019-10-24 00:35:00  2019-10-24 09:55:00  2019-10-24 08:55:01  2019-10-24 19:25:01
you@example.com        2019-10-24 02:35:00  2019-10-24 08:04:59  2019-10-24 08:45:02  2019-10-24 19:25:01
samadhanma@gmail.com   2019-10-24 01:10:00  2019-10-24 08:39:59  2019-10-24 09:00:02  2019-10-24 18:50:01
```

I want to find the average working hours.

```
select * from workinglogs where unix_timestamp(working_hours) < AVG(unix_timestamp(working_hours));
```

when I run this query it's not working.

Error showing:- FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10128]: Line 1:64 Not yet supported place for UDAF 'AVG'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could follow this approach

subquery to calculate the AVG and query to filter the output

as an example with your data

```
+------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------+--+
| workinglogs.user_name  | workinglogs.idle_hours  | workinglogs.working_hours  | workinglogs.start_time  | workinglogs.stop_time  |
+------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------+--+
| magadum@gmail.com      | 2019-10-24 02:15:00.0   | 2019-10-24 08:39:59.0      | 2019-10-24 08:30:02.0   | 2019-10-24 19:25:01.0  |
| yathink3@gmail.com     | 2019-10-24 01:30:00.0   | 2019-10-24 09:24:59.0      | 2019-10-24 08:30:02.0   | 2019-10-24 19:25:01.0  |
| shelkeva@gmail.com     | 2019-10-24 00:30:00.0   | 2019-10-24 09:10:01.0      | 2019-10-24 08:45:01.0   | 2019-10-24 18:25:02.0  |
| puruissim@gmail.com    | 2019-10-24 03:15:00.0   | 2019-10-24 07:19:59.0      | 2019-10-24 08:50:02.0   | 2019-10-24 19:25:01.0  |
| sangita.awa@gmail.com  | 2019-10-24 01:55:00.0   | 2019-10-24 08:40:00.0      | 2019-10-24 08:50:01.0   | 2019-10-24 19:25:01.0  |
| vaishusawan@gmail.com  | 2019-10-24 00:35:00.0   | 2019-10-24 09:55:00.0      | 2019-10-24 08:55:01.0   | 2019-10-24 19:25:01.0  |
| you@example.com        | 2019-10-24 02:35:00.0   | 2019-10-24 08:04:59.0      | 2019-10-24 08:45:02.0   | 2019-10-24 19:25:01.0  |
| samadhanma@gmail.com   | 2019-10-24 01:10:00.0   | 2019-10-24 08:39:59.0      | 2019-10-24 09:00:02.0   | 2019-10-24 18:50:01.0  |
+------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------+--+
```

query with subquery

```
WITH t AS(
SELECT ROUND(AVG(unix_timestamp(working_hours)),2) as average
FROM workinglogs)
SELECT w.user_name,w.idle_hours,w.working_hours,w.start_time,w.stop_time 
FROM workinglogs AS w,t
WHERE unix_timestamp(w.working_hours) < t.average;
```

output

```
+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+--+
|      w.user_name       |      w.idle_hours      |    w.working_hours     |      w.start_time      |      w.stop_time       |
+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+--+
| magadum@gmail.com      | 2019-10-24 02:15:00.0  | 2019-10-24 08:39:59.0  | 2019-10-24 08:30:02.0  | 2019-10-24 19:25:01.0  |
| puruissim@gmail.com    | 2019-10-24 03:15:00.0  | 2019-10-24 07:19:59.0  | 2019-10-24 08:50:02.0  | 2019-10-24 19:25:01.0  |
| sangita.awa@gmail.com  | 2019-10-24 01:55:00.0  | 2019-10-24 08:40:00.0  | 2019-10-24 08:50:01.0  | 2019-10-24 19:25:01.0  |
| you@example.com        | 2019-10-24 02:35:00.0  | 2019-10-24 08:04:59.0  | 2019-10-24 08:45:02.0  | 2019-10-24 19:25:01.0  |
| samadhanma@gmail.com   | 2019-10-24 01:10:00.0  | 2019-10-24 08:39:59.0  | 2019-10-24 09:00:02.0  | 2019-10-24 18:50:01.0  |
+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+--+
```

Comment: This code is using CTAS, this will reduce the performance. Here cartesian product will come into picture and generate lots of shuffled.

Comment: You cannot group by by timestamp, how do you get the average timestamp? I don't know, could you please give an example?

Comment: And the code above is not using CTAS(Create Table As Select), I'm not creating a table. The code above is using CTE(Common Table Expressions), and I didn't know about CTE performance issues, I think, It will depend on  the complexity of the query, but not on CTE expression itself. Please I am interested about CTE performance issues, if you could show some examples or articles about that, I will be pleased.

Comment: Please go through below link for cte performance: https://www.sqlshack.com/why-is-my-cte-so-slow/

Comment: I don't see the problem in that article with CTE. Precisely in the article  there are not problem with CTEs, but with particular queries that are recursive. Hive don't permit recursive CTE. Please read the conclusion.

Comment: Conclusion
Common Table Expressions are just another way to write subqueries. They are not magic, nor does SQL Server treat them any differently from normal, nested subqueries, except for their recursive cousins. CTEs can make code easier to read and maintain, since, when used properly, you can separate concerns by CTE. (Notice how I snuck in an Object-Oriented programming principle?) When they perform badly, though, don’t blame the CTE. Dig deeper to understand what is going on beneath the covers. The execution plan is the perfect way to do that.

Comment: And that article is about SQLServer, not about Hive so different SQL engines.

Comment: I couldn't be more agree with that article, query execution plan is the best way to know what is happening under the covers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using UDAF so you have to use group by. Select each column (don't use *) and then group by on selected columns.

```
Select col1, col2, col3,......coln from workinglogs group by col1, col2, col3,......coln having unix_timestamp(working_hours) < AVG(unix_timestamp(working_hours));
```

Comment: column user_name is unique how to use the group by here? @connecttopawan